# Django MultiSelect Choices with extra field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i want to have MultiSelectField with and extra field related to each of choices option. 
for example consider i have 5 option in my choices and i want to let the user to select some of them .it's not difficult to do this , but i want to let the user to fill one extra input per each option. (in django-admin and in the template)
how can i achieve this ?

## Models.py

```
city_names = (
    ('C1','City One'),
    ('C2' , 'City Two'),
    ('C3' , 'City Three'),
)

class City(models.Model):
    forms = MultiSelectField(max_length=2, blank=True , choices=city_names)
```

## Admin Panel:

with above lines i can let the user in the admin panel to select multiple choices from the `city_names` , but i want to have DateTime field for each option that user select.

## Example

- City 1     |---- DateTime for City 1
- City 2     |---- DateTime for City 2
- City 3     |---- DateTime for City 3

Comment: create a model for storing your choices, as by hardcoding you cannot achieve what you are looking for,

Comment: @Exprator as you see in the question i use a model for save them , but the problem is i want to store extra field per choice

Comment: i am not talking about that, the thing you hardcoded as choices, those needs to be in a model, so that when an user submits a new choice it will be saved in the database and next time will be rendered to the multifield, hope you can understand me